# SQL Server pivot one column and unpivot three columns.

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I am struggling with sql server where i want to pivot one column and unpivot three columns. and i do not find anything to aggregate upon.

I have data in this format:

```
UnAssigned  | Assigned   | InProgress | NotStarted | Date           | Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
31-08-2016  | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | September2015  | ABC
NULL        | 28-08-2016 | NULL       | NULL       | August2015     | XYZ
NULL        | NULL       | 05-08-2016 | NULL       | JULY2015       | XYZ
NULL        | 28-08-2016 | NULL       | NULL       | August2015     | ABC
NULL        | NULL       | 05-08-2016 | NULL       | JULY2015       | ABC
```

I need output in this format:

```
ABC          | September2015 | August2015 | JULY2015 
-----------------------------------------------------
UnAssigned   |       1       |      0     |     0  
Assigned     |       0       |      1     |     0 
InProgress   |       0       |      0     |     1
NotStarted   |       0       |      0     |     0

XYZ          | September2015 | August2015 | JULY2015 
-----------------------------------------------------
UnAssigned   |       1       |      0     |     0
Assigned     |       0       |      1     |     0
InProgress   |       0       |      0     |     1
NotStarted   |       0       |      0     |     0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really within sql's abilities to produce pretty reports, for that you would probably be better using excel or some kind of reporting tool like SSRS.
Having said that you could get close using this method:-

```
    DECLARE @T TABLE (UnAssigned VARCHAR(10),  Assigned VARCHAR(10),   InProgress VARCHAR(10) , NotStarted VARCHAR(10), Dt VARCHAR(20), Type VARCHAR(3))

    INSERT INTO @T VALUES
    ('31-08-2016'  , NULL       , NULL       , NULL       , 'September2015'  , 'ABC'),
    (NULL        , '28-08-2016' , NULL       , NULL       , 'August2015'     , 'XYZ'),
    (NULL        , NULL       , '05-08-2016' , NULL       , 'JULY2015'       , 'XYZ'),
    (NULL        , '28-08-2016' , NULL       , NULL       , 'August2015'     , 'ABC'),
    (NULL         , NULL   , '28-08-2016'    , NULL       , 'JULY2015'     , 'ABC')


    SELECT  dummytype type1,SRC,
            ISNULL([September2015],0) SEPTEMBER2015,ISNULL([August2015],0) AUGUST2015,ISNULL([JULY2015],0) JULY2015

    FROM
    (
    SELECT  'Unassigned' SRC,TYPE,type as dummytype,DT,CASE WHEN UNASSIGNED IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END obs FROM @T
    UNION
    SELECT  'Assigned' ,TYPE,'',DT,CASE WHEN ASSIGNED IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASSIGNED FROM @T
    UNION
    SELECT  'Inprogress',TYPE,'',DT,CASE WHEN INPROGRESS IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END INPROGRESS FROM @T
    UNION
    SELECT  'Notstarted' ,TYPE,'',DT,CASE WHEN NOTSTARTED IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NOTSTARTED FROM @T
    ) s
    pivot (sum(obs) for dt in ([JULY2015],[August2015],[September2015])) pvt

ORDER BY TYPE,
    CASE WHEN left(SRC,1) = 'U' THEN 1
        WHEN  left(SRC,1) = 'A' THEN 2
        WHEN  left(SRC,1) = 'I' THEN 3
        WHEN  left(SRC,1)  = 'N' THEN 4
    END
```

Result

```
type1 SRC        SEPTEMBER2015 AUGUST2015  JULY2015
----- ---------- ------------- ----------- -----------
ABC   Unassigned             1           0           0
      Assigned               0           1           0
      Inprogress             0           0           1
      Notstarted             0           0           0
XYZ   Unassigned             0           0           0
      Assigned               0           1           0
      Inprogress             0           0           1
      Notstarted             0           0           0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can unpivot and then pivot the data.. just use COUNT() as your aggregate in your pivot

```
DECLARE @tmpTable table 
    ([UnAssigned] DATETIME, [Assigned] DATETIME, [InProgress] DATETIME, [NotStarted] DATETIME, [Date] varchar(13), [Type] varchar(3))
;
INSERT INTO @tmpTable
    ([UnAssigned], [Assigned], [InProgress], [NotStarted], [Date], [Type])
VALUES
    ('2016-08-31', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'September2015', 'ABC'),
    (NULL, '2016-08-28', NULL, NULL, 'August2015', 'XYZ'),
    (NULL, NULL, '2016-08-05', NULL, 'JULY2015', 'XYZ'),
    (NULL, '2016-08-28', NULL, NULL, 'August2015', 'ABC'),
    (NULL, NULL, '2016-08-05', NULL, 'JULY2015', 'ABC')
;


WITH Sources AS (
    SELECT  Type, Src, Ord
    FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM @tmpTable) t
            CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1, 'UnAssigned'), (2, 'Assigned'), (3, 'InProgress'), (4, 'NotStarted')) ca(Ord, Src)
)
SELECT  s.Type,
        s.Src,
        September2015   = ISNULL(September2015, 0),
        August2015      = ISNULL(August2015, 0),
        JULY2015        = ISNULL(JULY2015, 0)
FROM    @tmpTable t
        UNPIVOT ( StatusDate  FOR Status IN (UnAssigned,Assigned,InProgress,NotStarted) ) up 
        PIVOT   ( COUNT(Date) FOR Date   IN (September2015,August2015,JULY2015) ) p
        FULL OUTER JOIN Sources s ON s.Type = p.Type AND s.Src = p.Status
ORDER BY s.Type,
        s.Ord
```